# How can I make JinvertScroll driven page load with page already scrolled left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, right-to-left

I'm a novice programmer and could use some help. I have a page I've built around the JinvertScroll Jquery code. I want the page to load with the images already scrolled, so that the user is in fact unscrolling, or rather, scrolling in what would normally be backwards. This is the page, so you can see what I'm trying to do (I want the text coming out of the dragon's mouth to load so that it will unfurl as the user scrolls the mouse wheel): http://xofer.net/test/

Comment: Is it something like this: https://frosty-hopper-193ff9.netlify.com/#load that you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've download the jInverScroll source code and changed the code a bit, in order for the scrolling effect to work backwards on your example. Here are the changes I've made to the original code and the library:

index.html / Before:

```html
  <div class="scroll section-1">
    <img src="images/horizon.png" alt="">
```

index.html / After:

```html
  <div class="scroll section-1" style="left:-2650px">
    <img src="images/horizon.png" alt="">
```

script.js / Before:

```js
$(function() {
    $.jInvertScroll([ '.scroll' ]);
});
```

script.js / After:

```js
$(function() {
    $.jInvertScroll([ '.scroll' ], {
        reverse: true,
        initialWidth: -2650
    });
});
```

[Source code for the library](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pixxelfactory/jInvertScroll/master/dist/js/jquery.jInvertScroll.js)

jquery.jinvertScroll.js / Before:

```js
// do the position calculation for each element
$.each(elements, function (i, el) {
    var deltaW = el.width() - winWidth;
    if (deltaW <= 0) {
        deltaW = el.width();
    }
    var pos = Math.floor(deltaW * scrollPercent) * -1;
    el.css('left', pos);
});
```

jquery.jinvertScroll.js / After:

```js
// do the position calculation for each element
$.each(elements, function (i, el) {
    if ( config.reverse ){
        var pos = ( config.initialWidth + ( Math.abs(config.initialWidth) * scrollPercent ) );
    } else {
        var deltaW = el.width() - winWidth;
        if (deltaW <= 0) {
            deltaW = el.width();
        }
        var pos = Math.floor(deltaW * scrollPercent) * -1;
    }
    el.css('left', pos);
});
```

Comment: Thanks KostasX, this looks like it will probably work with JinvertScroll. What I'd forgotten when I posted my question is that I ended up using a script someone had written around JInvertScroll, which allowed me to easily place divs overtop of the images. I'm using this code: https://s-nadolskiy.blogspot.com/2019/05/javascript-horizontal-scrolling.html Can I use this code to make it work with this tweaked version?

Comment: You sure can! It might need some refactoring, but you can go ahead and try. @ChristopherDickens

Comment: I got it figured out. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hey @KostasX. It looks like you gave me a solid answer for the code I was working with--a tweak on the JInvertScroll code. I went back to using the original JinvertScroll code instead, because the other one wasn't responsive. I'd really appreciate it if you could help me do the same thing to that.

Here's the original page you helped me with (this is what I'd like it to work like): http://xofer.net

And this is the page I'm trying to get to behave in the same way: http://xofer.net/examples/